# PySpark - Get the inserted row id after writing to PostgrSQL DB

Tags: python, postgresql, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using PySpark to write a DataFrame to a PostgreSQL database via JDBC command below. How can I get the inserted row id ? which is set as identity column with auto-increment.

I'm using below command, not a for-loop inserting each row separately.

```
df.write.jdbc(url=url, table="table1", mode=mode, properties=properties)
```

I know I can use monotonicallyIncreasingId and set the IDs within Spark, but I'm looking for an alternative where the DB handles the assignment, but I want to get he IDs back to use in other DataFrames.

I didn't find this in the documentation.

Comment: Are you asking this?  "After I insert these df rows into psql... how do i get back the unique_id of each row within my original df?"

Comment: Yes @HashRocketSyntax

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will be to query the table that you created and read that into a **new** data frame.

Alternatively, as you iterate over each row in either a for loop or generator, before you close the loop, fetch the ID of the record you just created and append each ID to a new column in the dataframe.